# R: Naming a map with elements from a column and naming its file with elements from another column in a dataframe with a forloop

Tags: r, for-loop, maps

I have georeferenced data in a dataframe called `dados` and I'm making maps from it with a forloop:

There's another dataframe, called `nomes`, that has the names of variables I want to plot in column `nomes` and variable labels

```
# A tibble: 18 x 3
index nomes                  label                                       
<dbl> <chr>                  <chr>                                       
1     1 v_a_s_emp_3112         Variação anual média: Total de empregados e~
2     2 v_a_s_emp_medio        Variação anual média: Soma do emprego medio~
3     3 v_a_emprego_total      Variação anual média: Emprego total (BNDES) 
4     4 v_a_h                  Variação anual média: Total de contratações 
5     5 v_a_s                  Variação anual média: Total de desligamentos
6     6 v_a_prop_emprego_3     Variação anual média: Proporção de estab. c~
7     7 v_a_estab              Variação anual média: Número de estabelecim~
8     8 v_a_emprego_medio      Variação anual média: Média de empregados n~
9     9 v_a_emprego_medio_ent~ Variação anual média: Média do emprego dos ~
10    10 v_a_nascimento_data    Variação anual média: Número de estab. entr~
11    11 v_a_nascimento_rais    Variação anual média: Número de estab. entr~
12    12 v_a_morte_rais         Variação anual média: Número de estab. ause~
13    13 v_a_tx_sobrev          Variação anual média: Taxa de sobrevivência~
14    14 v_a_n_solicitacao      Variação anual média: Número de estabelecim~
15    15 v_a_prop_idade_3       Variação anual média: Proporção de estab. c~
16    16 v_a_n_uso              Variação anual média: Número de estabelecim~
17    17 v_a_valorfinanc        Variação anual média: Valor financiado em R~
18    18 v_a_valor_invest       Variação anual média: Bens de investimento ~
```

The code that generates and saves the maps is this one and it works.

```
for (n in nomes$nomes) {

png(filename = paste("mapa_", n,".png", sep = ""), width = 1200,
height = 700, res = 200)

print(spplot(dados, c(n),
       col.regions = cores,
       at = intervalos,
       colorkey = list(at = c(-15, 0,20,40,60,80,100)),
       par.settings = my.settings,
       main = n) #title

)

dev.off()

}
```

The problem is the maps have names that are hard to understand and present.

[image]

I want the map's title to be the element in `nomes$label` in the same row of the element in `nomes$nomes` being plotted.

I've tried changing the `main` parameter and setting it equal to `nomes$label[n]`, but I get this error message:

```
Error in if (with(lab, is.null(label) || (is.character(label) && (label ==  : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Sadly I can't provide data for you to reproduce the maps fully because it's administrative. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work: change the `for` call as follows:

```
for (n in seq_along(nomes$nomes))
```

and replace every instance of `n` with `nomes$nomes[n]`. Then you can replace `main=n` with

```
main = nomes$label[n]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. One quick question: what is ````seq_along()```` supposed to do? Is it better to index for loops with it?

Comment: Great! `seq_along` generates a sequence (1,2,3...) of same length as the vector you pass to it. It's basically like doing `for (n in 1:length(vector))`. I'm sure it's more complicated than that, but that's as far as I can figure it out.